# how to make dnn jump to mobile skin when browser window is resized

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have installed dnn6 professional and was wondering how or if it is possible to change stylesheets based on browser window size. I figured that the Darkkight skin would have that type of functionality but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, rather than changing stylesheets, you would include styles for different sizes in the same stylesheet, using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).  DotNetNuke doesn't have anything specifically to assist with this, but also doesn't prevent you from using it in any way, either.

DotNetNuke does provide redirection based on device detection, so you can easily redirect users with a mobile device to a different URL (on the DNN site or not).  But changing the display of the site based on the screen size requires a skin with a responsive/adaptive design, which completely depends on the skin designer to implement.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I did find something on this on CSS tips and tricks.

Comment: Is there a way to mark your containers by numbers so that they show one after another in a certain way when responsive skin is used - when it shows one container under another on mobile device?